# Can't expand macros compiled by previous versions of Scala (scala 2.11.4, sbt 0.13.7, JDK 8)

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I'm converting a project to Scala 2.11.4 and sbt 0.13.7. I got a lot of errors, some of them are:

```
can't expand macros compiled by previous versions of Scala
[error]     preloadDevice <<= preloadDeviceTask
```

for this code:

```
lazy val settings: Seq[Setting[_]] = inConfig(Android) (Seq(
    // Preload Scala on the device/emulator
    preloadDevice <<= preloadDeviceTask,
    preloadEmulator <<= InputTask(
      (sdkPath)(AndroidProject.installedAvds(_)))(preloadEmulatorTask),

    // Uninstall previously preloaded Scala
    unloadDevice <<= unloadDeviceTask,
    unloadEmulator <<= InputTask(
      (sdkPath)(AndroidProject.installedAvds(_)))(unloadEmulatorTask)
  ))
```

How do I fix it?

**UPDATE:**

**JDK 8**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does sbt give "can't expand macros compiled by previous versions of Scala" for Def.inputTask macro in Scala 2.11.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103043/why-does-sbt-give-cant-expand-macros-compiled-by-previous-versions-of-scala-f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From here: [Why doesn't the Def.inputTask macro work in Scala 2.11.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103043/why-does-sbt-give-cant-expand-macros-compiled-by-previous-versions-of-scala-f)

> In your build.sbt file, make sure you scalaVersion := "2.10.4" instead
>   of something like scalaVersion := "2.11.x"

If you use JDK 8, there is not too much options as Sbt 0.13.x compiled against Scala 2.10.x:

- use JDK7 for sbt only (by setting specific JAVA_HOME for sbt in your run-script) - your project will still be compiled against JDK8
- try JDK8 + Scala-2.10 for sbt (it may work but no guarantees of course)
- build sbt 0.13 against JDK8 [by yourself](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1399)

Comment: I'm using JDK 8, it can't be Scala. 2.10.4